# React-native fetch post for login page

Tags: python, react-native, authentication, fetch

I have a login page in React-Native and I tried to fetch post request, to see if the user is in the database.

```
const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

const loginData = () => {
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            username: username,
            password: password,
        })
    })

        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (!data.error) {
                props.navigation.navigate("Home", { data: data })
            }
            else {
                Alert.alert('invalid data');
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
            Alert.alert('invalid data');
        });
```

And I get this error on bad credential:
JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "IntegrityError"
at [native code]:null in parse

Comment: Is your backend written in Django by any chance? If that's the case you're running into some kind of database integrity failure.

Comment: don't do `response.json()`, do `response.text()`, console log the error to see it. Once you fix it, use `response.json()`

Comment: Thanks, that worked.

In my Django backend I use this rest_framework ModelViewSet

class CustomUserViewSets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    
     queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
     serializer_class = CustomUserSerializer
     lookup_field = 'username'

@action(detail=True)
def group_names(self, request, pk=None):
            
            user = self.get_object()
            groups = user.groups.all()
            return Response([group.name for group in groups])



When I try to log in a new user is created. What should I do?